# Django unicode Multi language

Tags: django, python-2.7, unicode, django-models, django-forms

I am using Django1.7 ,python2.7 and for multi language data store , am put  Mysql collation  is utf8_unicode_ci. I have 2 issue.

1. I have two model A and B , Model A have dropdown Of Model B, When I Create a Model B record in multi language, am getting error if I put unicode in Model B structure.
2. When I remove  unicode in Model B structure , am did't getting dropdown value in Model A Form, it showing only object.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have to write __unicode__ method in your model and return the name you want.

Comment: Yes, for dropdown in Model A Form. If am write unicode method while creating Model B record it's showing error ,but dropdown in Model A Form showing value. If remove unicode Method in Model B it's not showing dropdown value in Model A Form  , It showing only object but creating record is working properly.

Comment: What kind of error you get?

Comment: Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xB2\xA4\xE0\xB3\x86...' for column 'object_repr' at row 1 , While creating

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I fix the issue. this "Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xB2\xA4\xE0\xB3\x86...' for column 'object_repr' at row 1 " error is coming from django_admin_log table , we put object_repr collation is utf8_unicode_ci .